# How to store the result of each iteration of a for loop into an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration

This question could also be (depending on how you look at it) - How to use a for loop to do a basic math operation that adds up the sum of the multiples of 3

So I am doing Problem 1 of Project Euler.

I've (already) hit a steel-reinforced wall. I could use some help - with just a specific portion of the problem please (I am not looking for just an answer to the problem, but rather, an answer to my specific problem so I can carry on with trying to solve the remainder problem using any answer you guys provide me here)...

Anyways.

I (think I) created a for loop that will give me the multiples of 3. However, I'm trying to store the result of each iteration of the for-loop so that it adds up to the sum of those multiples i.e. I'm trying to store the result from each iteration of the loop - whether it be into an array or into a variable that takes the sum of the multiples - it doesn't matter to me - I wouldn't mind learning both methods.

I'm sure this sounds kind of confusing so let me paint my picture w/ an example...

I have a for-loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
var x = 0;
x += (i * 3);
WHAT DO I DO NEXT????
```

^ So I would think that this gives me x with a value of 3 upon the 1st iteration of the loop, x with a value of 9 on the 2nd loop, and x with a value of 18 on the final loop. That's correct, right? (if this were returning 18 I don't think I would need to store the values of each iteration into an array)

1st iteration:

```
i = 1; x = 0
```

Original equation...

```
(i * 3) + x
```

So...

```
(1 * 3) + (x = 0) = 3
```

So after completion of the 1st loop, x has a value of 3, right???
(Question: How would I store this value of x (which is 3) - how would I store it in an array while in this stage of the for loop?)

2nd iteration of loop:

```
i = 2; x = 3

(2 * 3) + (x = 3) = 9
```

(same question as before: how would I add this value to an array?)

3rd iteration:

```
i = 3; x = 9

(3 * 3) + (x = 9) = 18
```

Q: shouldn't this be the final value of x upon completion of the for loop??? For some reason, when I run the code, the final value of x is 9, and not 18

So, basically I am trying to add the sum of the 3 values...But what do I do next? I thought my for loop would add the result of the equation after each loop to x, but instead of ending up w/ 18 (the sum of `3 + 6 + 9`), x's value was 9???

Should I use an array? If so, I'm thinking I could add the return value to an array, but I'm not sure how to add the result of each iteration of the loop to an array. Maybe the following?...

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
var array = [];
x = 0;
x += (i *3); 
array.push(x);
};
```

^ I tried running that in jfiddle, but it would only add the last value of x (9) into the array... So how would I add the value of x to an array *after each iteration of the for loop*??? And I'm not seeing what's wrong with my for-loop to where it's returning a value of x as 9?

Also, I'm assuming the euler problems get significantly more difficult as we progress? If so, I've got a TON of work/practice to do....

THANKS IN ADVANCE...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create the array once, and push the result at each iteration to the array:

```
var array = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var x = 0;
    x += (i *3); 
    array.push(x);
}
```

Or for that matter, just use this:

```
var array = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    array.push(i *3);
}
```

Or to simply get the sum of the factors, use this:

```
var x = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    x += i *3;
}
```

Comment: WOW Thank you.  I had the strongest feeling that my code was close, but I was just making a noob mistake... THANK YOU for the quick response. It's amazing how this process (getting a legitimate coding question answered) takes 31 minutes - 30 minutes to write the question and 1 minute to get an answer!!! THANKS AGAIN!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `var x = 0` and `var array = []` at every step of the loop, try something like:

```
var array = [], x = 0;
for (i=1; i<4; i++){
  x += (i*3); 
  array.push(x);
}
```

Comment: Same as I wrote in the other answer - THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:
and you have to define `X` out of the loop

```
var array = [],
x = 0;
for (i=1; i<4; i++){
  x += (i*3); 
  array.push(x);
}
```