# How to get each iteration in a for loop into a list/vector? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am attempting to take a value N, and create a list/vector with all of the values from N to 0 (not inclusive), and then N again.

After defining N, I have the following code:

```
for (int i = N; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

This neatly prints out the required values. For example, with N=3:

```
3
2
1
3
```

The issue is that I can't manipulate these to compute what I want to (namely the mean, range, maximum and minimum values). So what I need to do is to get each iteration to put itself into an array, the same array that the previous iteration put itself in.

I have found a similar question on here ([How to store the result of each iteration of a for loop into an array (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801995/how-to-store-the-result-of-each-iteration-of-a-for-loop-into-an-array-javascrip)), except it's in javascript, which is causing some issues for me.

Why does the following not work on C++, and how can I change it?

```
var array = []
for (int i = N-1; i < N; i--) {
    array.push(i);
}
```

The same thing with int replacint var does not work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i add elements to an empty vector in a loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984268/how-do-i-add-elements-to-an-empty-vector-in-a-loop)

Comment: First of all, the `for (int i = N-1; i < N; i--) {
    cout << i << endl;
}` won't result in printing `3 2 1 3`. I suggest first to run your code, then ask what's wrong with it

Comment: Your first `for` loop keeps running semi-infinitely (i.e. it definitively runs until it reaches `INT_MIN`, and after that - it's undefined behavior).

Comment: "Why does the following not work on C++, and how can I change it?" You can't just make up syntax. In C++ `for (int i = N-1; i < N; i--)` would invoke [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). C++ is not Js and vice versa, and they have very different common paradigms and idioms, you'll have to learn them separately.

Comment: Code edited to what it should be, wasn't concentrating when I typed up the Q.

Comment: `int N = 3; vector<int> array; for (int i = N; i > 0; i--) array.push_back(i); array.reverse( array.begin(), array.end() );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this: `var array = []`, and the rest of your code, is not  `c++` syntax at all, it's pure javascript. You can't copy code from one language to another expecting that would compile and run properly.

In order to insert all elemnts from N to 0 and then N again to a vector you need to :

1. include the vector library : `#include <vector>`
2. initiate an N value (from a user, using `cin` in by including iostream for example OR manually, i.e. N = 6)
3. Read through the following code to see how to enter all numbers wanted numbers to a vector [here (use push_back)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984268/how-do-i-add-elements-to-an-empty-vector-in-a-loop). **Note:** Also, as @NathanOliver mentioned, you can use reverse if you know N in advanced. look here for [simple reference.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/)
4. And then, push also N in the end manually (`vec.push_back(N)`)

**And I'm really saying that for you, try to work this out yourself** before someone here gives you the complete code.

Comment: A call to reserve would also be good if you know up front how many elements you are going to get.

Comment: @NathanOliver +1 for that, I added it.